# How to replace llvm-ld with clang?

Tags: llvm, clang, ld

**Summary:** `llvm-ld` has been removed from the [LLVM 3.2 release](http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/docs/ReleaseNotes.html).  I am trying to figure out how to use clang in its place in my build system.

*Note that I figured out the answer to my own question while writing it but I am still posting it in case it is useful to anyone else. Alternative answers are also welcome.*

**Details**:

I have a build process which first generates bitcode using `clang++ -emit-llvm`.  Then I take the bitcode files and link them together with `llvm-link`.  Then I apply some standard optimization passes with `opt`.  Then I apply another custom compiler pass with `opt`.  Then I apply the standard optimization passes again using `opt` a third time.  Finally I take the output from the last run of `opt` and use `llvm-link` to link with appropriate libraries to generate my executable.  When I tried to replace `llvm-link` with `clang++` in this process I get the error message: `file not recognized: File format not recognized`

To make this question more concrete I created a simplified example of what I am trying to do.  First there are two files that I want to compile and link together

**test1.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getNum();

int main()
{
  int value = getNum();
  printf("value is %d\n", value);
  return 0;
}
```

**test2.cpp**

```
int getNum()
{
  return 5;
}
```

I executed the following sequence of commands:

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -c test1.cpp test2.cpp
llvm-link -o test.bc1 test1.o test2.o 
opt test.bc1 -o test.bc2 -std-compile-opts
```

*(Note that I am currently running llvm 3.1, but I'm trying to figure out the steps that will work for llvm 3.2.  I assume that I should be able to make the LLVM 3.1 version work correctly using clang instead of llvm-ld)*

Then if I run:

```
llvm-ld test.bc2 -o a.out -native
```

everything is fine and `a.out` prints out 5.

However, if I run:

```
clang++ test.bc2 -o a.out
```

Then I get the error message:

```
test.bc2: file not recognized: File format not recognized clang-3:
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Obviously I know that I can produce an executable file by running clang directly on the .cpp files.  But I'm wondering what the best way to integrate `clang` with `opt` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test case described in the question can be compiled using the following steps:

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -c test1.cpp test2.cpp
llvm-link -o test.bc1 test1.o test2.o 
opt test.bc1 -o test.bc2 -std-compile-opts

llc -filetype=obj test.bc2 -o test.o
clang++ test.o
```

This produces a working `a.out` file.

It seems that `llc` is needed to convert from bitcode to machine code which can then be processed by `clang` as it normally would.

Answer (score 1):

In general I've found that

```
llvm-ld x.bc y.bc
```

can be replaced with

```
llc x.bc
llc y.bc
clang x.s y.s
```