# What is an alternative for a linker command from llvm 2.9 to llvm 3.3?

Tags: c++, linker, llvm

In llvm 2.9 I used to work with this linker command "llvm-ld -lname hello.bc -o hello -L/path". However, "llvm-ld" has been removed in newer version of llvm. I know that people recommend using "llvm-link" or "clang" instead but I could not see any replacement for -lname in any of these two. Could anyone help me what command I could use instead?

Comment: Not sure if `lld` is a "replacement", or just a completely different product... http://lld.llvm.org/

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779958/llvm-ld-still-exist-for-clang-3-4) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595906/how-to-replace-llvm-ld-with-clang)? By `-lname` you mean link library `libname.so`? If so, it didn't change (at least for `clang`).